# Bash scripting ls with spaces in the argument, when the argument is coming from an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have the following code:

```
entries=("Wet\ Picnic" "Arizona\ Jones" "Bikeboy")
for arg in "${entries[@]}"; do ls -lh $arg.* ; done
```

It gives me 4 errors and 1 success.  I'd really like it to give me 3 successes.

How do I handle the fact that the arguments to `ls` contain spaces (I've obviously tried escaping them as that's how it is currently), but to no avail.

The console output is currently.

```
ls: Wet: No such file or directory
ls: Picnic: No such file or directory
ls: Arizona: No such file or directory
ls: Jones: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 17:55 Bikeboy.png
```

SO it's clearly splitting on the space.  Even though it's escaped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're escaping in the wrong spot.  Try this example:

```
entries=("Wet Picnic" "Arizona Jones" "Bikeboy")
for arg in "${entries[@]}"; do ls -lh "$arg".* ; done
```

It should work fine. Here's a complete example, including the "People's Stage" you mentioned in the comments:

```
$ ls
Arizona Jones.png   People's Stage.png  example*
Bikeboy.png         Wet Picnic.png
$ cat example 
#!/bin/bash

entries=("Wet Picnic" "Arizona Jones" "Bikeboy" "People's Stage")
for arg in "${entries[@]}"; do ls -lh "$arg".* ; done
$ ./example 
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff     0B Jun 27 10:00 Wet Picnic.png
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff     0B Jun 27 10:00 Arizona Jones.png
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff     0B Jun 27 10:01 Bikeboy.png
-rw-r--r--  1 carl  staff     0B Jun 27 10:11 People's Stage.png
```

Comment: However...  If I had `entries=("Wet Picnic" "Arizona Jones" "Bikeboy" "People's Stage")` - how would I escape the apostrophe?

Comment: @MattFellows - did you try it?  It works exactly the same, no changes required.